# Share data between two tabs having different URL

Tags: jquery, angular

Okay so i have two applications, one is a java application and second is an angular application. The java application has a web portal which has a logged in user. When the user clicks on a link on the web portal i open a new tab which runs the angular application. What i need is to pass the username from the web portal to the angular application. I tried using storage but as the web portal runs on localhost:8099 and the angular application runs on localhost:4200 i am not able to share data. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the java application Web View?

Comment: Yes it is @Cohen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use url parameters to pass the username if the username are not sensitive data. For example:

> http://www.example.com?username=randomname.

From other tab, capture the query parameters from url and use it for your purpose.

Comment: Okay now I feel pretty dumb for not realising that. Thanks for the help